# Not send email in digital ocean server

Tags: java, email, timeout, sendmail

I have an app stored in digital ocean that before was stored in other server. 
Before my app send email normally, now I got error:
I already check firewal stuff, iptables config, change port and etc. In my local environment the email flows normal, if I deploy back in my older server the email flows normal.
What more can be?

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed :      smtp-mail.outlook.com:25
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.simplemail.DefaultMailer.wrapUpAndSend(DefaultMailer.java:74)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.simplemail.DefaultMailer.send(DefaultMailer.java:63)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.simplemail.DefaultAsyncMailer$1.call(DefaultAsyncMailer.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.simplemail.DefaultAsyncMailer$1.call(DefaultAsyncMailer.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp-mail.outlook.com, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
```

Comment: Hi, On DigitalOcean's VMs you only need inform the SMTP server as 'localhost' without authentication credentials. All VMs are a 'SMTP server' naturally.

Comment: I'm use vraptor.simplemail, I will change to localhost this [way here](https://gist.github.com/andregnhoato/4158a0da001400c4ce1c) and not work. nothing in logfile.

Comment: Based on your vraptor.environment config, SSL must be 'false'. Try with this. 'vraptor.simplemail.main.ssl = false'

Answer (score 3):

After contacting the digital ocean support and opening a ticket informing this problem, I was informed that, they have a spam block activated by default for new accounts, being necessary contact to validate the owner identity.